# Why does this fail?

Tags: flowtype

Live example [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgN0aKBeKBvAUFKZCAJwCMAuKAZ2GMQDsBzXAX111EigGEB7AW34R6weElToseAkTKUA5HAFCR81uwBmAV3oJEvelAAmvAMrAtGjVAAUAQz0SQlMSjQgAlDja4l9GlBKgsKiju6UfMEirk6YOIQkFFCKyiHyUGx+AQA2iADWEDHhsGGS8bJJ8rkF6T4m5pYaNtWFpZ649RZWNkEqoeLuHkA).

```
type Activity = {
  verb: string
}

type CommentActivity = {
  verb: 'comment'
}

function doStuff (activity: Activity) {}

const commentActivity: CommentActivity = { verb: 'comment' }
const likeActivity: Activity = { verb: 'like' }

doStuff(likeActivity)
doStuff(commentActivity)
```

Fails with:

```
15: doStuff(commentActivity)
            ^ Cannot call `doStuff` with `commentActivity` bound to `activity` because string literal `comment` [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `verb`.
References:
6:   verb: 'comment'           ^ [1]
2:   verb: string           ^ [2]
```

The error message is clear and I know how to work around this, but I don't understand why a string literal isn't considered a valid string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue of property variance. If you have a function like `doStuff` with the type

```
(activity: Activity): void => {}
```

then it is perfectly valid for the function do to

```
function doStuff (activity: Activity) {
    activity.verb = "some new verb";
}
```

and that 100% typechecks. What that means is that if

```
doStuff(commentActivity)
```

were allowed, `doStuff` would actually *change the type* of `commentActivity`, which is why this is throwing an error for you.

What you need to do is tell Flow that you will not be changing the value of `.verb`, essentially making it read-only inside of `doStuff`. To do this, you put a `+` before the name of the property.

```
type Activity = {
  +verb: string
};
```

([On Flow/try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgN0aKBeKBvAUFKAamQgCcAjALigGdhTEA7Ac1wF9ddRIoBhAewC2giI2DwkqdFjwESFagHI4QkWMXtOAMwCujBIn6MoAE34BlYDq1aoACgCGBqSGoSUaEAEocHXCsY6KBVhUXFnT2oBULF3F0wcKHkqKGVVMMUoDgCggBtEAGsIOMjYCOlE5KV8osy-M0trLTsa4vLvXAarGzsQtXDJTy8gA))